# How to validate if CORS is properly set on my S3 bucket?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, cors, progressive-web-apps, amazon-cloudfront

I have this resource on available via cloudfront cdn 
https://d2t70e97bm7kcz.cloudfront.net/app_pfsandbox01/staticapi/MenuTree.json

The S3 bucket is public and the file path is
https://s3.amazonaws.com/appsres/app_pfsandbox01/staticapi/MenuTree.json

The S3 bucket has the following CORS settings

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
 <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
 </CORSRule>
 </CORSConfiguration>
```

I want the resources in this bucket to be used in several different apps (PWAs) with different domains without having to set up a specific CDN for each app/domain.
I need to know how to validate if this resource will be fetched from any app under any domain?

Thanks

Comment: The simplistic way is just to try it, try to access the data from JavaScript on a different domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used https://apitester.com/

Crafted a custom OPTIONS request using 
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: https://dummydomain.com

[image]

Got a succesfull response:

[image]